# how to set image url from local drive for json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I m new angularjs tool.

Here is my json file,

```
[
  {
   "name": "WORLD",
   "population": 6916183000,
   "flagurl":"C:\xampp\htdocs\selva
\Flag_of_the_People's_Republic_of_China.svg"
  },
  {
   "name":"More developed regions",
   "population": 1240935000,
   "flagurl": "C:\xampp\htdocs\selva
\Flag_of_the_People's_Republic_of_China.svg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Less developed regions",
    "population": 5675249000,
    "flagurl": "C:\xampp\htdocs\selva
\Flag_of_the_People's_Republic_of_China.svg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Least developed countries",
    "population": 838807000,
    "flagurl": "C:\xampp\htdocs\selva
\Flag_of_the_People's_Republic_of_China.svg"
  }
]
```

when i run my below code, it doesn't working,

```
<script>
var myapp=angular.module('myapp',[]);
myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope,$http) {
$http.get('flag.json').success(function(data){
$scope.countries=data;
});
});
</script>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
search: <input type="text" ng-model="query" />
<table>
<tr>
<th>country</th>
<th>population</th>
<th>flag</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries"> 
<td>{{country.name}}</td>
<td>{{country.population}}</td>
<td><img src="{{country.flagurl}}" width="100"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but when i fetch image from online, it works fine.

May i know, what is my mistake in my code?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the error output you received?

Comment: it just didn't display all the data.. when in web console it shows like this http://s11.postimg.org/6t26jy4ir/untitled.jpg

Comment: Can you add the error message in the image to the post?

Comment: I meant you should copy and paste it in the question post. This will help people arrive at a solution.

Comment: The JSON is invalid. You should check it in a validator.

Comment: yes.. it shows error.. but i just confused how to fix the error..

Comment: can anyone please help me to fix this json error?.. thanks

Comment: Check the JSON file in a validator: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: hi.. in json validator didn't show error now.. but my output page looks like this http://s27.postimg.org/ebz49yglv/untitled.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the result of the images not being loaded. The images should be referenced based on their relative location to the `index.html`. Because the images are in the same directory as the `index.html`, there is no need for the file reference.

To load the images properly, you should refactor the JSON in this manner:

```
{
  "flagurl": "Flag_of_the_People's_Republic_of_China.svg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have stopped allowing access to local resources in default mode (not sure about ie) anyway you can start chrome like this "chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files" to allow you to do this